# How to retrive documents by multiple fields using $in operator

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection

```
db.list.insert({ first: "apple", second: "banana" });
db.list.insert({ first: "apple", second: "tree" });
db.list.insert({ first: "space", second: "moon" });
db.list.insert({ first: "medal", second: "sport" });
```

I have an array of pairs

```
ary = [ [ "apple", "tree" ], [ "space" , "moon" ], [ "medal", "sport" ] ]
```

Currently I am doing

```
result_list = []
for a, b in ary
    result_list.push db.list.find({ first: a, second: b })
result_list # => [ { first: "apple", second: "tree" }, { first: "apple", second: "tree" }, { first: "apple", second: "tree" } ]
```

Is it possible to retrive documents by multiple fields using $in operator with only 1 query?

If I wanted to retrive only by one field, I would do

```
db.list.find({ "first": { "$in": ary_of_some_words } })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in` should work equally well for objects as it does for primitive values, but anyway if you're looking for a top-level object that matches one of the parameter combinations, you don't even need `$in`; `$or` should do the trick.

Basically, all you have to do is convert `ary` into an array of objects instead of arrays, and then you should be able to use these objects as the possible filters passed to `$or`.

Assuming you have a `toObject` function that receives an array of length 2 and returns an object with "first" and "second" properties, the code might look something like this:

```
var ary = [ [ "apple", "tree" ], [ "space" , "moon" ], [ "medal", "sport" ] ];
var object_ary = ary.map(toObject);
db.list.find({ $or: object_ary });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does work. Tricky solution :)